# PHP: Order of array keys is not coming up correctly

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array (large) with with 120 rows and each row having 5 columns.  At the end I tried to add three more rows but only the last three columns.  First I added dummy char * to the rows (3) I wanted to append.  In a loop, these three rows (each three columns) are added.
Problem is - the first row that is added at the end of main row, the order of keys is lost!!
Example of Output (showing only the last part):

```
[116] => Array ( [0] => A3 [1] => B4 [2] => C2 [3] => D4 [4] => * ) 
[117] => Array ( [0] => A3 [1] => B5 [2] => C2 [3] => D2 [4] => * ) 
[118] => Array ( [0] => A3 [1] => B5 [2] => C2 [3] => D3 [4] => * ) 
[119] => Array ( [0] => A3 [1] => B5 [2] => C2 [3] => D4 [4] => * ) 
[120] => Array ( **[4]** => * [0] => * [1] => * [2] => * [3] => * ) **<==== Observer this row**
[121] => Array ( [0] => * [1] => * [2] => * [3] => * [4] => * ) 
[122] => Array ( [0] => * [1] => * [2] => * [3] => * [4] => * )
```

If you see row 120, [4] came in the start, instead of [0]!

Code Used to populate dummy * :

```
$i = 0;
for ($i=0;$i<=count($unMatchedRows)-1;$i++){
    for ($jCols = 0; $jCols<=($pNoOfCols+$pStartCol-1); $jCols++){
        $pMainArray[$vRowsOfMainArray+$i][$jCols] = '*';
    }
}
```

Code used to update the last three rows:

```
$i=0;
$ColToStart = $pStartCol-1;
foreach ($unMatchedRows as $rowNumberOfCompArray) {
    for ($jCols = 0; $jCols<=$pNoOfCols; $jCols++){
        echo "<br /> Value of Colstart: ".($ColToStart+$jCols);
        $pMainArray[$vRowsOfMainArray+$i][$ColToStart+$jCols] =       $pCompArray[$rowNumberOfCompArray][$jCols];

    }
    $i++;
}
$pStartCol = 3 and $pNoOfCols = 2;
```

Did a echo of row and col values and things are shown up perfect!!
Even on retriving, i could get the right values ... like for [0] and [4] I was getting right values.

**Problem** is need to feedback the above array in the visual environment and it is not showing up correctly.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your problem, but the keys will appear in the same order they are appended to the array.

You can use `ksort()` to sort an array based on the keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot for support, savageman!

Found the issue. Looks like, while populating * in the last column (before updating with few values), looped through the count of array, which will be 1 more as array starts with 0.
Instead of 119 rows, had 120 rows with one column updated and it created all the issue!!